# CMake: Why would I use `target_link_libraries(x PUBLIC y)`?

Tags: c++, cmake

I've read the CMake documentation and built a mid-size project correctly with CMake, using only `PRIVATE` and `INTERFACE` linkage. From this standpoint, I think I understand what `PRIVATE`, `INTERFACE`, and `PUBLIC` library linkage all mean. The issue is that from what I understand, `PUBLIC` library linkage does not seem like something I'd ever want in *any* C++ project.

[From the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#command:target_link_libraries):

> Libraries and targets following `PUBLIC` are linked to, and are made part of the link interface. Libraries and targets following `PRIVATE` are linked to, but are not made part of the link interface. Libraries following `INTERFACE` are appended to the link interface and are not used for linking `<target>`.

I believe this means that if I write `target_link_libraries(x PRIVATE y)`, then `libx.a` will be linked with `liby.a`. If I write `target_link_libraries(x INTERFACE y)`, then `libx.a` will not be linked with `liby.a`, but anyone who links against `libx.a` will also be linked against `liby.a`. So far, so good!

But `target_link_libraries(x PUBLIC y)` seems to mean that `libx.a` will be linked with `liby.a`, *and* anyone linking against `libx.a` will also get linked against `liby.a`, *again*. Wouldn't this result in `liby.a` getting linked in twice and violating ODR? Why would I ever want this?

Comment: You get it a bit wrongly. `libx.a` will be linked with `liby.a` - no, .a is not linked privately to any libraries. It makes sense for executables and shared libraries.

Comment: @273K: Are you saying that `target_link_libraries(x PRIVATE y)` does nothing if `x` is a `STATIC` library?

Comment: No, "nothing" is not a correct word. It makes a dependency `libx.a` of `liby.a`.

Comment: The whole question is interesting. I can only guess that `PUBLIC` is useful for quick switching between STATIC and SHARED w/o changing other CMakeLists.txt parts.

Comment: There other things that target_link_libraries() does. Because its a dependency it add additional include directory settings and other properties from the dependent target.